# Suggestions to cluster more than 300k observations

Tags: r, clustering, large-data, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I am trying to perform an hierarchical clustering on data frame that contains 300k records 7 features (3 binaries and 4 continuous) in order to get insights on what looks like my dataset. 
I've chosen hierarchical in order to avoid defining the number of clusters.

While trying to execute `dist()` function, it prompts me the following output `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 340.7 Gb`

So I searched on internet alternatives and I've came on the `DBSCAN` package in R to try to cluster, instead of a distance matrix, a density method so the RAM does not get exhausted.

Since for `eps` is suggested to calculate `K`, then I've used `kNNdistplot(d, k = 5)`. It throw a plot with almost no knee as shown below.
[image]

Even though, I've toyed a little with the function and tried a specific K but I'm still receiving issues for bad memory allocation 
`Error in dbscan_int(x, as.double(eps), as.integer(minPts), as.double(weights) : std::bad_alloc`

So, my question would be if you could provide me guidance on if keep insisting with density based clustering or try a different algorithm/method.

I'm running my analysis on Ubuntu Server with 16 gb RAM on AWS. If more is required, then would you please suggest a reasonable amount to handle that dataset.
We expect the dataset to growth so if a Hadoop cluster would be useful for clustering, then feel free to comment.

Thank you very much.

Comment: check out the [clustering task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) and search for "large" in the page?

Comment: Thank you! I'll review the functions marked for large datasets and share the output.

Comment: I've used the `genie` package which implements a different version of `hclust` which uses more CPU than RAM, which allowed me to cluster. I'm still playing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scaling to even more data, use a sample.

1. If you cannot get useful results on a sample, you won't be able to get it to work on the full data...
2. Clustering is statistical aggregation. The results should not be very much different from a sample to the entire data set, or they are probably wrong. So if you have too much data, break it into partitionsz analyze each, and validate that you find the same on each partition.

Clustering big data is big nonsense. People need to get sane again and stop hyping everything, in particular if it clearly doesn't work in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I've also tried to sample a meaningful dataset smaller than the large one. Most of internet information points to random sampling while I would like to have a more robust approach to keep same proportion of the information in a reduce set. Do you know any approach or package to sample information keeping proportions?

Comment: Random sampling, in particular when done repeatedly, is a pretty reliable way to keep all proportions well enough. Stratification approaches introduce other problems. Why do you think it is necessary to do so?

Comment: What is the approach to repeatedly perform sampling and clustering? You sample, cluster, save the result and the repeat? Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Yes. Or you just partition your data in subsets of the desired size. The interesting part is how to compare results for validity testing... But you'll first need to get *one* useful result before you even need to consider validity...